# Autoencoder not learning walk forward image transformation

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, autoencoder

I have a series of 15 frames with (60 rows x 50 columns). Over the course of those 15 frames, the moon moves from the top left to the bottom right.

> Data = https://github.com/aiqc/AIQC/tree/main/remote_datum/image/liberty_moon

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am attempting a walk forward autoencoder where:

- The input data is a 60x50 image.
- The evaluation label is a 60x50 image from *2 frames later.*
- All data is scaled between 0-1.

```py
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(64*hp['multiplier'], 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool1D( 2, padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(32*hp['multiplier'], 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool1D( 2, padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(16*hp['multiplier'], 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPool1D( 2, padding='same'))

    model.add(layers.Conv1D(16*hp['multiplier'], 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.UpSampling1D(2))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(32*hp['multiplier'], 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(layers.UpSampling1D(2))
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(64*hp['multiplier'], 3, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.UpSampling1D(2))

    model.add(layers.Conv1D(50, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same'))
    # last layer tried sigmoid with BCE loss.
    # last layer tried relu with MAE.
```

Tutorials say to use a final layer of sigmoid and BCE loss, but the values I'm producing must not be between 0-1 because the loss goes way negative.

[image]

If I use a final layer of relu with MAE loss it claims to learn something.

[image]

But the predicted image is notttt great:

[image]

Comment: Am I just not using enough layers for that amount of pixels?

Comment: Please explain the experiment. How are you generating a new image? Is the image count=15?

Comment: Yes, the count is 15. I screenshotted a video of the moon and cropped them to the exact dimensions using PIL.

Comment: Here is exactly how I am running the experiment https://aiqc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/keras_image_forecasting.html

Answer (score 0):

Image auto-encoders are great for **style change**, but not so great for **content change**.

Anyways, as you keep ~95% untouched in your transformation, a `ResNet` would probably be very helpful!
If you use an `hourglass network`, you shall see it quickly converging into a self-encoder (which is ~95% right) and than focus all the training just on the difference (the moon part).